# What's the best way to check for errors before leaving a row in a DataGridView

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

As far as I can tell, the best way to do this is do it in the DataTable.RowChanging event. But what if I want to cancel the action? There is no EventArgs.Cancel option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the DataTable.RowChanging event handler, you can throw an exception to cancel the change.  The exception will be thrown to the piece of code making the change where you can handle it appropriately.

Comment: Hmm. That makes sense - but isn't throwing an exception a costly operation?

Comment: costly compared to just manipulating a local variable - sure...  but are you planning on this happening hundreds of times per second?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the `DataGridView`, if you throw an exception in `DataTable.RowChanging`, you can handle it in `DataGridView.OnError`. Setting `EventArgs.Cancel` to `true` preserves data entry.